# Xdebug remote host VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, xdebug

I'm using VSCode and this plugin https://github.com/felixfbecker/vscode-php-debug .

I'm attempting to use Xdebug on a remote host.

I am able to run Xdebug successfully with breakpoints when I run the local instance of the web app I'm debugging.

When I go to the web address, I get this in the remote logs:

```
Log opened at 2020-12-01 06:25:23
I: Checking remote connect back address.
I: Checking header 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'.
I: Checking header 'REMOTE_ADDR'.
I: Remote address found, connecting to my_local_ip_address:9000.
E: Time-out connecting to client. :-(
Log closed at 2020-12-01 06:25:23
```

On my localhost, when this happens, I'm getting an entry in my tcpdump as well, so it seems to be connecting, but it is not connecting within VSCode.

When I run `telnet my_local_ip_address 9000` from my remote host, I get an almost identical tcpdump on my localhost, as well as this message from the debug log within VSCode:

```
<- launchResponse
Response {
  seq: 0,
  type: 'response',
  request_seq: 2,
  command: 'launch',
  success: true
}

new connection 1
```

So telnet does not seem to have a problem connecting from the remote host to my localhost, so it doesn't seem to be a connectivity problem.

But when I start Xdebug in VSCode, I get the remote logs filled, and my Xdebug console stays like this:

```
<- launchResponse
Response {
  seq: 0,
  type: 'response',
  request_seq: 2,
  command: 'launch',
  success: true
}
```

and does not echo any connection.

My remote php.ini variables look like this:

```
zend_extension="xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_log=/tmp/xdebug.log
```

I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: I'm not using VSCode (using different PHP IDE)... but it might be some path mapping issue. Or maybe VSCode only works with sessions **initiated** from the editor and not when initiated from outside (e.g. perhaps it needs to know the server/site name in order to accept it). You need to provide your VSCode debug settings (start with "Set `"log": true` in your launch.json")